# Outlook 2010 screwed up: how to fix?

Tags: windows-7, crash, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, imap

I am an Outlook 2010 user with multiple email addresses (like 99% of people around here). 3 of my accounts are IMAP and one is Exchange.

I had Outlook set up with the two IMAPs and the Exchange, then wanted to add the other IMAP.

I followed the procedure but I have been unable to complete it due to an unknown error.

I also tried to delete the Exchange account and add it again. I did some tries, but now Outlook refuses to start: "Unable to open Outlook main window". Safe mode is of no help, compaibility mode only performs online crash report but no more result.

I tried to delete the Outlook directory in my user's AppData directory, but it seems it tries to re-create the .pst files that were originally in.

Please also note that I have a WinMo PDA in sync with Outlook. I would like to reset it to factory defaults. I don't care about emails deleted because all messages are on their respective servers.

What do you suggest me to do since removing AppData's subdirectory has no effect?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: Maybe I don't currently have the DVD at hand ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete your profile and recreate it:

- Go to control panel
- Find `Mail`
- Find and delete your profile (or create a new one and change the default to the new one)
- Set everything back up

Comment: :) Great! It worked. It also has been explained on http://techvirgin.com/2009/12/how-to-reset-microsoft-outlook-to-default-settings/

Comment: Glad I could help. I did this a lot at my tech support job.